# Spyder crashes on startup and the reset command doesn't work because it cannot find spyderlib.spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I have recently been using Spyder until it crashed today. On startup, it said to please use

```
python spyder --reset
```

if the problem persists. However when I run this command I get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\Python27\scripts>python spyder --reset
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spyder", line 2, in <module>
    from spyderlib import start_app
ImportError: No module named spyderlib
```

I also tried another suggestion and got similar results

```
C:\Program Files\Python27\scripts>python -c "from spyderlib.spyder import main;
main()" --reset
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named spyderlib.spyder
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using Spyder through an Anaconda installation?  If so, you can try opening the Anaconda Prompt and typing:

conda update spyder 

or

conda install spyder

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same issue, with Spyder 3.2.8, Anaconda 3.5, Python 3.6 and Windows 10. I fixed it by running anaconda prompt as admin and run
conda upgrade --all

Maybe reinstall the entire Anaconda and upgrade all packages?

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by using:

```
conda uninstall spyder

conda install spyder
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, I solved mine by uninstalling pylint and reinstalling it.